# NodeJS passport unknown authentication strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am currently working on a node js project with passport authentication.
But i get the following error message:

Error: "Unknown authentication strategy "

Here is my Code:

```
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var UserModel = require('../models/user');

module.exports = function(passport){
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        return done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, done){
    process.nextTick(function(){
        User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }

            if(user){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signUpErr', 'The mail is taken'));
            } else {
                var newUser = new UserModel();
                newUser.name = username;
                newUser.password = newUser.generateHash(password);

                newUser.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                        throw err;
                    }
                    console.log('All Ok');
                    return done(null, newUser);
                })
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

}

Route:

```
//Post requests
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect : '/signup'
}));
```

My model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String
});

UserSchema.method.generateHash = function(password){
    return bcrypt.hash(password);
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserSchema);
```

I would really need your help, thanks!

Comment: How/where are you calling the module that configures Passport (your first block of code)?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with almost exactly the same code. It comes from a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you passing the strategy along with the user credentials

```
 var credentials = {
     username:"username",
     password:"password",
     strategy:"local"

            };
 $http.post('auth/signin', credentials);
```

Server side

```
function passportAuthenticate(req, res, next, strategy) {
    passport.authenticate(strategy, function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            res.status(400).send(info);
        } else  {
            next(req, res, user);
        }
    })(req, res, next);
}
```